# Show a list of Illnesses based on selected Symptoms

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Currently I am using richfaces picklist in JSF to select a number of Symptoms such as headache, sore throat and so on. These selected symptoms are then passed on to the results form and the Symptom id's are displayed.

I'd like to be able to:

1. Display the Symptom names instead of the symptom id's
2. Display matching illnesses in a table

Illnesses are linked to symptoms in a separate table with a record for each symptom that matches an Illness.

SymptomBean:

```
private List<Symptom> newSymptomList = new ArrayList<Symptom>();

public List getNewSymptomList()
{
  return newSymptomList;
}

public void setNewSymptomList(List<Symptom> newSymptomList )
{
  this.newSymptomList = newSymptomList; 
}

public List getAllSym() {
    List allSymptoms = new ArrayList(); 
    //code connects to db and loops through each symptom
    while (rs.next()) {
        allSymptoms.add(i,new Symptom(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));

return allSymptoms;
}

public class Symptom{
public String symptomId;
public String symptomName;

    public Symptom(String symptomId, String symptomName){
    this.symptomId = symptomId;
    this.symptomName = symptomName;
    }

public String getSymptomId(){
    return symptomId;
    }

public String getSymptomName(){
    return symptomName;
    }
}      
}
```

Result.xhtml: (to display symptom id's)

```
#{sym.newSymptomList}
```

Current output format for displaying the symptom id's: [1,2,4]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ui:repeat` to display the names:

```html
<ui:repeat value=#{sym.newSymptomList} var="item">
  <h:outputText value="#{item}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Format the output as you like.